# Errors when attempting to run Sphinx on some GIMP Python Plugin code

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-sphinx, gimp, gimpfu

I am trying to use Sphinx to document a Python file, which is being used to implement a GIMP Plugin. The problem is, when I run;

```
make html
```

I get the following messages - which as can be seen below, yield an error;

```
sphinx-build -b html -d _build/doctrees   . _build/html
Running Sphinx v2.2.0
loading pickled environment... done
building [mo]: targets for 0 po files that are out of date
building [html]: targets for 0 source files that are out of date
updating environment: 0 added, 1 changed, 0 removed
reading sources... [100%] code                                                                                                                        
WARNING: autodoc: failed to import module 'Plugin_ImageOverlay'; the following exception was raised:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/craig/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/sphinx/ext/autodoc/importer.py", line 32, in import_module
    return importlib.import_module(modname)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/importlib/__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 986, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 969, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 958, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 673, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 665, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 222, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/home/craig/.gimp-2.8/plug-ins/ImageOverlay/Plugin_ImageOverlay.py", line 73, in 
  <module>
    from   gimpfu import register, main, pdb, gimp, PF_IMAGE, PF_DRAWABLE, PF_INT, 
    PF_STRING, PF_FILE, PF_BOOL, INTERPOLATION_NONE, INTERPOLATION_LINEAR, 
    INTERPOLATION_CUBIC, INTERPOLATION_LANCZOS, PF_RADIO
  File "/usr/lib/gimp/2.0/python/gimpfu.py", line 235
    raise error, "parameter name contains illegal characters"
               ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

looking for now-outdated files... none found
pickling environment... done
checking consistency... done
preparing documents... done
writing output... [100%] index                                                                                                                        
generating indices...  genindexdone
writing additional pages...  search/home/craig/.local/lib/python3.5/site-
packages/sphinx_rtd_theme/search.html:20: RemovedInSphinx30Warning: To modify script_files 
in the theme is deprecated. Please insert a <script> tag directly in your theme instead.
{{ super() }}
done
copying static files... ... done
copying extra files... done
dumping search index in English (code: en)... done
dumping object inventory... done
build succeeded, 1 warning.

The HTML pages are in _build/html.

Build finished. The HTML pages are in _build/html.
```

In case it is not obvious from the above output, the error message reads;

```
  File "/usr/lib/gimp/2.0/python/gimpfu.py", line 235
    raise error, "parameter name contains tllegal characters"
               ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

I don't know a great deal about Python or Sphinx, but does this error have something to do with the differences in syntax between Python versions 2 and 3? My Plugin can be loaded and executed without any problems by GIMP - so why does Sphinx seem to choke on it?

Is there some easy workaround for this that I'm not aware of, such as a key-value pair that can be placed in Sphinx's conf.py file?

Thanks in advance for any assistance.

Comment: Mocking gimpfu might work: https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/usage/extensions/autodoc.html?highlight=mocking#confval-autodoc_mock_imports

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're using version 2.2.0 of Sphinx, and Sphinx [dropped support for Python 2 since 2.0.x](https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/changes.html#incompatible-changes)

The `raise error, e` style in gimpfu.py is [not supported in Python 3.x](http://python-future.org/compatible_idioms.html#raising-exceptions). (you're expected to use `raise error(e)`)

You could try using an older version of Sphinx that supports Python 2, or hacking gimp to use a Python 3 compatible syntax, or asking the gimp people to fix it...

Comment: Or possibly make Sphynx ignore/exclude the Gimp stuff.

Comment: I tried hiding the gimpfu module from Sphinx by commenting out the relevant Python  from ... import ... statement. All this did was create other problems further down the source code file. I had started editing the gimpfu.py file when I thought I should stop and ask a question about it first, here on Stack Overflow. I thought that maybe Sphinx might have a setting such as use_python_major_version = '2', which I simply could have enabled in the project's conf.py file. Thank you for all the helpful feedback.